# How do I get my subclassed combo box messages to forward their messages to the parent toolbar?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have five combo boxes on the toolbar and I want to process their messages and notification , particularly CBN_SELCHANGE notification int the subclassed toolbar class. I have tried several approaches to no avail. The deinition of the tool bar and combo box classes are shown below:

```
#pragma once
// CMyComboBox

class CMyComboBox : public CComboBox
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CMyComboBox)

public:
    CMyComboBox();
    virtual ~CMyComboBox();

protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    afx_msg BOOL OnCbnSelchange();
    //afx_msg void OnCbnSelchange();
};





// MyComboBox.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MyComboBox.h"


IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CMyComboBox, CComboBoxEx)

CMyComboBox::CMyComboBox()
{

}

CMyComboBox::~CMyComboBox()
{
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyComboBox, CComboBoxEx)
    //ON_CONTROL_REFLECT(CBN_SELCHANGE, &CMyComboBox::OnCbnSelchange)
    ON_CONTROL_REFLECT_EX(CBN_SELCHANGE, &CMyComboBox::OnCbnSelchange)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()



// CMyComboBox message handlers


BOOL CMyComboBox::OnCbnSelchange()
{
    return FALSE;
}


#pragma once
#include "MyStatic.h"
#include "MyComboBox.h"

// MyToolBar

class CMyToolBar : public CMFCToolBar
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CMyToolBar)

public:
    CMyToolBar();
    virtual ~CMyToolBar();

public:
    void EmbedControls();
    //CMyStatic m_pStatic3;
    CMyComboBox m_Combo1,m_Combo2,m_Combo3,m_Combo4,m_Combo5;
    CWnd m_pEdit1;
    CFont m_font;
private:
public:
    afx_msg void OnCbnSelchange1();
    afx_msg void OnCbnSelchange2();
    afx_msg void OnCbnSelchange3();
    afx_msg void OnCbnSelchange4();
    afx_msg void OnCbnSelchange5();
protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
//public:
    //afx_msg void OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy);
};




IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CMyToolBar, CMFCToolBar)

CMyToolBar::CMyToolBar()
{
}

CMyToolBar::~CMyToolBar()
{
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyToolBar, CMFCToolBar)
    ON_CBN_SELCHANGE(ID_COMBO1, &CMyToolBar::OnCbnSelchange1)
    ON_CBN_SELCHANGE(ID_COMBO2, &CMyToolBar::OnCbnSelchange2)
    ON_CBN_SELCHANGE(ID_COMBO3, &CMyToolBar::OnCbnSelchange3)
    ON_CBN_SELCHANGE(ID_COMBO4, &CMyToolBar::OnCbnSelchange4)
    ON_CBN_SELCHANGE(ID_COMBO5, &CMyToolBar::OnCbnSelchange5)
    //ON_WM_SIZE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()



// MyToolBar message handlers
#include "stdAfx.h"
#include "MyToolBar.h"
void CMyToolBar::OnCbnSelchange1()
{
  //Operation1
}

void CMyToolBar::OnCbnSelchange2()
{
 //Operation1
}

void CMyToolBar::OnCbnSelchange2()
{
 //Operation2
}

void CMyToolBar::OnCbnSelchange3()
{
 //Operation3
}

void CMyToolBar::OnCbnSelchange4()
{
 //Operation4
}

void CMyToolBar::OnCbnSelchange5()
{
 //Operation5
}

void CMyToolBar:EmbedControls()
{
//Creates five comboboxes of type MyComboBox and embeds then on the tool bar
}
```

The problem is that neither of operations 1 to 4 is being carried out signifying that selection change messages were not reaching the toolbar. Stepping into the code at runtime also confirm this.

So, how do I get the combo boxes to forward messages to the toolbar for processiing?

Comment: [Walkthrough: Putting Controls On Toolbars](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983718.aspx): *"In MFC, a toolbar button must be a [CMFCToolBarButton Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983678.aspx)-derived class, for example [CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982770.aspx), ..."*

Comment: `class CMyComboBox : public CComboBox` + `IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CMyComboBox, CComboBoxEx)` do you see it ?

Comment: OK. I see it.Thanks.